# run and monitor process in background

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, monitoring, process

I want to run some php file in background and monitor them , what is the best option for me ?

I have used nohup , but it is really simple an can not monitor processes well

I need only monitor which process is still alive ,  automatically restart , CPU usage or any useful info

Comment: And what do you want to monitor - is it running/terminated, how much cpu/mem/net does it use etc.?!? Try to be more particular ...

Comment: I need only monitor which process is still alive ,  automatically restart , CPU usage or any useful info

Comment: What you want tto minitor after running you php file in background?

Comment: @AbhishekAnandAmralkar : is it alive , process lists , memory usage and any usefull info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to deploy `monit` what is a nice utility to manage and monitor processes, files and much more. You can monitor a process and its CPU usage with such simple configuration then:

```
check process your_php_script
        matching "your_php_script"
        start program = "/home/user/bin/your_php_script
        stop program = "/usr/bin/pkill your_php_script
        if cpu usage > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
```

Briefly, it will check for a running process "`your_php_script`". If it's not running it will start it and if it uses more than 80% of CPU for more than 5 cycles it will restart the process (cycle/polling interval is configured in monit daemon configuration file in `/etc/monit.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Pandora FMS monitoring software](http://pandorafms.com/Community/download/en). With this tool you can perform [processes and services monitorization](http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Operations#Service_monitoring_and_service_watchdog) and also some basic monitoring (CPU, Disk, RAM,...).
In fact I think that there are some plugins developed for the Apache Server in the module library.